# Excel formula to return a unique count based on multiple criterias

Tags: excel

I have a Gantt chart in Excel, which hosts a lot of functionality. The main issue is that smallest task duration has to be a day, however there are certain tasks that can be done in a couple of hours. I'm trying to count the actual duration of days taken across the entire project, for a given type of task.
See sample below.

[image: Gantt Chart screenshot]

The following tasks shown on the screenshot, represent a single day

- 1.4.3
- 1.5.3
- 1.6.3
- 1.7.3

However, given the restrictions on the overall design, a typical formula would return 4 days.

The closest formula that partially works for me, is as follows.

```
=IFERROR(1/SUM(IF(COUNTIFS($E$8:$E$2000,$E$8:$E$2000, $B$8:$B$2000,"Commissioning")=1,1,0)),0)
```

I have tried pivot tables, however they don't quite work for me, and they add a great overhead to the document.

Thank you in advance for any support.

Regards,
Alain

Comment: I'm confused. Why not `1.3.3` and `1.8.3`?  Please post a copyable version of sample data input and a screenshot of desired output.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for your reply. Yes, 1.3.3 and 1.8.3 also need to be added as part of the total sum. I was just trying to make it clear, that 1.4.3, 1.5.3, 1.6.3 and 1.7.3 are tasks that can be done on the same day, and therefore needed to be calculated as a single day. In essence, the expected result should be 3 days for the data shown in the screenshot, instead I’m getting 6 days.

Comment: Do you  also need to account for overlaps?  If that's the case, when you post the copyable data sample and the screen shot of your desired output, be sure to have some examples of that.  Pretty certain it can be done easily in Power Query (available in Excel 2010+)

Comment: Hi Ron, thank you for your reply. I end up going with your idea of Power Query, which solved my problem. Thank you!